# How to check differentiability

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have a function for which I'm supposed find the points between (-5,5) where the function in not differntiable
I tried it with graphical approach which is way too time consuming and with general method (1st principle) of derivative which is also quite lengthy, so is there any other concept or approach which can be used for solving

[image: function]

Comment: Don't be afraid of lengthy terms, it's good calculus practice. 

Hint: You can square both expressions (because if $f(x)$ is differentiable, also $(f(x))^2$ would be differentiable.) Then you can compute the derivatives a bit easier.

Also, it might be smart to use the second binomial formula in the first expression to see how it is related to the second case. You get something like $\sqrt{(x-n)(n+1-x)}$.

Comment: Thanks alot will keep this in mind

Comment: Please do not use tags that have no business here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in I$ and we are showing where $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{(2n+1)x-x^2-(n^2+n)}\hspace{4mm} x\in[n, n+0.5)\\
n+1 - x\hspace{40mm}x\in[n+0.5,n+1)\end{cases}$$
It is clear that $f$ should be differentiable if $x\in(n+1.5,n+1)$. Now in $(n, n+0.5)$, we first recognize that $g(y) = \sqrt{y}$ is only differentiable if $y>0$. So for $f$ to be differentiable on $(n,n+0.5)$ we must have that
$$ \begin{align*}(2n+1)x-x^2-(n^2+n) &> 0\newline 
x^2 - (2n+1)x+(n^2+n) &< 0\end{align*}$$
You can use the quadratic formula to see that the roots of $x^2-(2n+1)x+(n^2+n)$ occur at $n$ and $n+1$ respectively. Thus you can plug in values to find that $ \sqrt{(2n+1)x-x^2-(n^2+n)}$ is certainly differentiable on $(n,n+1)$. Hence $f$ is differentiable on $(n,n+0.5)$. The place left to verify are at $n+0.5$ and $n$ for each $n\in I$.

You can see that $f'(x) = -1$ on $(n+0.5, n+1)$ and on $(n-0.5,n)$. But on $(n,n+0.5)$ we use chain rule to find that
$$ f'(x) = \frac{2n+1-2x}{2\sqrt{(2n+1)x-x^2-(n^2+n)}}$$
This function is continuous and
$\lim_{x\to n^-} f'(x)$ does not exist and similarly $\lim_{x\to (n+0.5)^+}f'(x)$ does not exist. Hence is $f$ differentiable as long as $x\not= -4.5,-4,-3.5,etc.$